# Every website is showing untrusted certificate warning on all browsers

Tags: windows, security, browser, ssl, certificate

[image]

I'm on windows 7. Every website is showing untrusted security warning. I tried every browser that I have. I tried using https. This is extremely odd, it never happened before, well it could happen to 1 site or 2 sites, but now it's happening to every site.

Say I go to google, and it says, ""do you accept the risk?" and i said yes, the second time I go to google, it will ask the same question.

One small note, I don't know if it's related to the issue or not, I'll mention it anyway, I changed the harware time on Linux and now windows clock  is wrong, I don't know if it has anything to do with the issue.

Another thing that I notice and I don't know if it's related to the issue or not. I'll mention it too. some websites aren't loading correctly, for example chess.com, I use ad blocker

[image]

I have been a user on chess.com for more than 3 years and never seen the error "This webpage is not avail"

Also, the internet is extremely slow, I don't know if it's related. And lastly, the certificates seems legit, here's google certificate

[image]

Comment: I can't test on linux because it doesn't  have internet, the wifi drivers aren't working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your system time. Certificates are valid only for certain periods of time. If it was just one site, I'd be suspicious. Multiple sites? Either time/date, or malware